# Shading of imported STL

Tags: stl, interpolation

There is a new import option "STL" while the previous STL import has been renamed to "STL legacy". The new one is much faster, but it adds some inter-vertex shading interpolation which makes technical objects look strange or even confusing. What is a flat panel looks like a convex protrusion etc. There are a lot of such shading artifacts which obfuscate the view of the object.

Can that interpolated shading be prevented somehow, so that a single triangle has only a single color resulting only from the angle between its normal and the light direction?